# SQLite selecting/filtering a Table and limit the output

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm doing a SQL project for school I have this table:

```
 name        price_gold  price_euros  role        universe
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  -----------------
Sylvanas    10,000      9,99         Specialist  World of Warcraft
The Lost V  10,000      9,99         Specialist  The Lost Vikings
Azmodan     10,000      9,99         Specialist  Diablo
Zagara      7,000       8,49         Specialist  Starcraft
Murky       7,000       8,49         Specialist  World of Warcraft
Abathur     10,000      9,99         Specialist  Starcraft
Gazlowe     4,000       6,49         Specialist  World of Warcraft
Nazeebo     10,000      9,99         Specialist  Diablo
Sgt. Hamme  7,000       8,49         Specialist  Starcraft
Artanis     10,000      9,99         Warrior     Starcraft
Rexxar      10,000      9,99         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Leoric      10,000      9,99         Warrior     Diablo
Johanna     10,000      9,99         Warrior     Diablo
Anub'arak   4,000       6,49         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Chen        7,000       8,49         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Arthas      7,000       8,49         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Diablo      7,000       8,49         Warrior     Diablo
E.T.C.      2,000       3,99         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Muradin     2,000       3,99         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Sonya       4,000       6,49         Warrior     Diablo
Stitches    7,000       8,49         Warrior     World of Warcraft
Tyrael      4,000       6,49         Warrior     Diablo
Cho                                  Warrior     World of Warcraft
Gall                                 Assassin    World of Warcraft
The Butche  10,000      9,99         Assassin    Diablo
Kael'thas   10,000      9,99         Assassin    World of Warcraft
Thrall      10,000      9,99         Assassin    World of Warcraft
Jaina       4,000       6,49         Assassin    World of Warcraft
Tychus      4,000       6,49         Assassin    Starcraft
Falstad     7,000       8,49         Assassin    World of Warcraft
Illidan     4,000       6,49         Assassin    World of Warcraft
```

And I want to query a select of 5 different roles and 5 random names i.e. this:

```
name        role
----------  ---------
Sylvanas    Specialis
The Lost V  Specialis
Azmodan     Specialis
Zagara      Specialis
Murky       Specialis
Johanna     Warrior
Anub'arak   Warrior
Chen        Warrior
Arthas      Warrior
Stitches    Warrior
The Butche  Assassin
Kael'thas   Assassin
Thrall      Assassin
Jaina       Assassin
Tychus      Assassin
Lt. Morale  Support
Kharazim    Support
Reghar      Support
Brightwing  Support
```

I tried using `Limit` but that only gives the first 5 elements of the table.

What to do?

Edit1:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT hero.name, hero.role 
    FROM hero
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT role FROM hero
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) n
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t1

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT hero.name, hero.role
    FROM hero 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT role FROM hero
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) n
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t2

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT hero.name, hero.role
    FROM hero
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT role FROM hero
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3) n
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t3

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT hero.name, hero.role
    FROM hero
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT role FROM hero
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4) n
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t4

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT hero.name, hero.role
    FROM hero
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT role FROM hero
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5) n
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t5
```

This is the code you sent after I changed it to work with my table @Parfait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using union queries of 5 random names for each distinct role. Because `UNION` queries do not support multiple `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, table aliases are used. Offsets are used to go down the list of distinct roles.

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT g.name, g.role 
    FROM games g
    WHERE g.role = 'Specialist'
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t1

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT g.name, g.role 
    FROM games g
    WHERE g.role = 'Support'
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t2

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT g.name, g.role 
    FROM games g
    WHERE g.role = 'Warrior'
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t3

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT g.name, g.role 
    FROM games g
    WHERE g.role = 'Assassin'
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t4

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT g.name, g.role 
    FROM games g
    WHERE g.role = 'Admin'
    ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5) As t5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the 5 roles you want, you could use limit on 5 subqueries and then union them together:

```
select name, role from mytable where role = 'Support' limit 5
union all
select name, role from mytable where role = 'Assassin' limit 5
union all
select name, role from mytable where role = 'Warrior' limit 5
union all
select name, role from mytable where role = 'Specialist' limit 5
union all
select name, role from mytable where role = 'Mom' limit 5
```

SQL's not super good at random row selection, though if you have row ids, you could use a rand() (if you are using mysql) and use that to choose a random row id. The limit 5 that you mention and I use is likely to return a very similar set of rows each time.

Comment: Thanks! that's definitively going to help

Comment: but doesn't quite do the trick sqlite does not seem to like the `limit 5` at the end of the sub-querys and says: `Error: LIMIT clause should come after UNION ALL not before` I'll keep at it still and thanks of couse

Comment: Aha, I was using MySQL syntax, it lets you use limit there. I'm guessing you will need to do some fancy footwork with subqueries perhaps alongside a rand and row number if SQLite has them.